# Impossible to operate on custom type after it is encoded? Spark Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, kryo, apache-spark-encoders

Say you have this (solution of encoding custom type is brought from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset)):

```
// assume we handle custom type
class MyObj(val i: Int, val j: String)
implicit val myObjEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[MyObj]
val ds = spark.createDataset(Seq(new MyObj(1, "a"),new MyObj(2, "b"),new MyObj(3, "c")))
```

When do a `ds.show`, I got:

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
+--------------------+
```

I understand that it's because the contents are encoded into internal Spark SQL binary representation. But how can I display the decoded content like this?

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  c|
+---+---+
```

---

**UPDATE1**

Displaying content is not the biggest issue, what's more important is that it could lead to problem when processing the dataset, consider this example:

```
// continue with the above code
val ds2 = spark.createDataset(Seq(new MyObj(2, "a"),new MyObj(6, "b"),new MyObj(5, "c"))) 

ds.joinWith(ds2, ds("i") === ds2("i"), "inner") 
// this gives a Runtime error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "i" among (value);
```

Does this mean, `kryo`-encoded type is not able to do operation like `joinWith` conveniently?

> **How do we process custom type on `Dataset` then**?
> If we are not able to process it after it's encoded, what's the point of this `kryo` encoding solution on custom type?!

(Solution provided by @jacek below is good to know for `case class` type, but it still cannot decode **custom type**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me, but seems like using high-level API to do low-level (deserialization) work.

This is not to say it should be done this way, but shows that it's possible.

I don't know why KryoDeserializer does not deserialize bytes to the object the bytes came from. It is just this way.

One major difference between your class definition and mine is this `case` that let me using the following trick. Again, no idea exactly why it makes it possible.

```
scala> println(spark.version)
3.0.1

// Note that case keyword
case class MyObj(val i: Int, val j: String)
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
implicit val myObjEncoder = Encoders.kryo[MyObj]
// myObjEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[MyObj] = class[value[0]: binary]

val ds = (Seq(new MyObj(1, "a"),new MyObj(2, "b"),new MyObj(3, "c"))).toDS
// the Kryo deserializer gives bytes
scala> ds.printSchema
root
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)

scala> :type sc
org.apache.spark.SparkContext

// Let's deserialize the bytes into an object
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
val ks = new KryoSerializer(sc.getConf)
// that begs for a generic UDF
val deserMyObj = udf { value: Array[Byte] => 
  import java.nio.ByteBuffer
  ks.newInstance.deserialize(ByteBuffer.wrap(value)).asInstanceOf[MyObj] }

val solution = ds.select(deserMyObj('value) as "result").select($"result.*")
scala> solution.show
+---+---+
|  i|  j|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  c|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean each time when displaying a dataset (of custom type, e.g. defined by `case class`), or writing to disk, we have to do the `ks.newInstance.deserialize` first? That quite confuses me about the usage of encoders in `Dataset`.

Comment: Not sure I understood you correctly, but since you've used `kryo` things have changed a bit. Stick to `case class` and `import spark.implicits._` and you should be just fine. In other words, why have you considered `Encoders.kryo`? I rarely see its use.

Comment: For the type that is not within [the list](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala) of predefined encoders, [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset) we have to use `kryo`, no? If we use it, `ds` is in binary format rather than tabular, which prevents further transformation and data processing (imagine you want to do a simple `joinWith` on the column `i` with another `ds`, you have to do `ks.newInstance.deserialize` first, which is really not convenient).

Comment: For unsupported types you have to convert them to the ones that are supported. No need for kryo.

Comment: In fact, when i pasted your code in spark-shell, i got this error (Spark 3.0.1) in the step of **`.asInstanceOf[MyObj]`**: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type MyObj is not supported
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$schemaFor$1(ScalaReflection.scala:743)
  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:69)`

Comment: @jack You may have missed this `// Note that case keyword` in my code, didn't you?

Comment: That is true! But then it is not the solution i'm looking for, because i wouldn't encode a `case class` object using `kryo`, with `import spark.implicits._` i already got the benefits from Spark's default encoders. I'm looking for solution to decode/deserialize custom type encoded by `kryo`

Comment: I cannot imagine how i can work on the encoded custom objects, if i don't deserialize it. Or say, what's the point of using `kryo` if i cannot decode back?

Comment: Thank you @Jacek, your comment about converting custom type into case class inspires me!